# Umbraco - Unable to navigate to sections other than Content after upgrade to 4.5.2

Tags: upgrade, umbraco

I've tried posting this on the Umbraco forums to no avail. Hoping to find some help here.

I thought I upgraded successfully from 4.0.4.2 to 4.5.2 (on my way to 4.8...) as I received no errors and everything seemed to go smoothly. However, in the backoffice, when I click on any section other than Content, I get redirected back to Content. I can manually reach each section by typing in the name of it after the # sign like: #media, but as soon as I click on a tree item, it redirects me back to Content. Any ideas would be appreciated.

Comment: can you tell what are the steps you taken to upgrade?

Answer (score 0):

2 thoughts:

1. You're cacheing some of the old javascript in your browser. Try clearing your cache. IE can be stubborn in this regard; preferably try in Chrome.
2. Personally, if your site is working under 4.5.2, I wouldn't sweat the back office issue and just continue with the upgrade to 4.8.1. There will likely be new problems to solve there anyway :) and the backoffice issue may go away.

Comment: Thx. That crossed my mind. Just not sure if I should upgrade with that issue. I will try and post back the results this afternoon.

Comment: Updating the icons via the following script fixed this problem. Links must run off the appIcon field. Not sure why this is not executed when the database is updated via the 4.5.2 upgrade.

update umbracoApp set appIcon = '.tray' + appAlias where appAlias IN ('content','media','users','settings','developer','member')

Answer (score 0):

Updating the icons via the following script fixed this problem. Links must run off the appIcon field. Not sure why this is not executed when the database is updated via the 4.5.2 upgrade.

update umbracoApp 
set appIcon = '.tray' + appAlias 
where appAlias IN ('content','media','users','settings','developer','member')